# How to write $I$ and $I_0$ as a symbol?

Tags: symbols, custom-notation

How could we write both $I$ and $I_0$ as a symbol in Wolfram Mathematica? I consider $I$ as a variable and $I_0$ as a parameter in my system of equations ($Y=C_0 + I, I=I_0+bY$, Y and I are endogenous variables). I have tried to define as <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>. It does not work to solve the system of equations.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question closed as a duplicate!? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229544/how-to-write-i-and-i-0-as-a-symbol

Comment: `I` is the imaginary number in Mathematica. Do not use it as a variable or parameter name - use something else.

Comment: You could use capital iota, which looks only slightly different from an `I` and would be easily confused with it.  You can't use both `X` and `Subscript[X, 0]` as independent variables because the second depends on `X` explicitly.  Use the Notation package to define it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write $I$ and $I_0$ as a symbol](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229544/how-to-write-i-and-i-0-as-a-symbol)

Comment: In our discipline, these are standard types of equations. Is there any way we could write these equations in Mathematica and get the solution? I should mention here that I could get the solution if I change the variables and parameters.

Comment: To expand on what @flinty said, you cannot use `I`; or at least, you shouldn't.  It is `Protected` and very likely used by internal, behind-the-scenes functions, and redefining it will break those functions.  If you should call one of them, it will give you the wrong answer or even crash the kernel. You could use `$PreRead` to change `I` to something else internally, say `myI`, on input and use `MakeBoxes` to write `myI` as a plain `I` on output.